# How to get user input? Python

Tags: python, user-input

I'm very new to this, so please be gentle!

As a little bit of work for my Python course, I am learning to run user input code. I put together the below code but when I run it using command-B, it asks me the 'What's your name?' question, but when I type in my name and click enter, nothing happens? For info, I am using Python 3.7, and using SublimeText.

I am 100% sure this is an easy answer, but surprisingly I cannot find the answer, and I have searched a little bit on here, and generally via Google, etc.

```
name=input("What's your name?:")
print("Hi",name,"how do you do.")
age=input("How old are you",name,"?:")
print("Great",name,"I'm",age,"years old too.")
city=input("Which city do you come from",name,"?:")
print("What a coincidence, I am from",city,"too.")
print(name,", here is your record //")
print(name, age, city)
```

Thanks for any help, and if you guys have an tips for a super newbie, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Confused about your "click enter", don't you press the <RETURN> key on your keyboard?

Comment: Hi, apologies, I meant I click the enter key on my keyboard, which I thought was key to register the data, i.e. I answer Rob to the first input, and then the code should show; Hi Rob, how do you do.

Comment: Its your use of the work "click" that confuses me, are you using a mouse for that or pressing the key on your keyboard?  Have you tried using the command-line to run your program?  It seems you are using some strange environment to execute your code.  Which Operating System are you using?

Comment: Having trawled through some comments on https://realpython.com/setting-up-sublime-text-3-for-full-stack-python-development/ it seems that Sublime Text has issues with `input()`.  I suggest you use the command-line to execute your code.

Answer (score 0):

You are having some issues because you have few syntax errors. The following is your code with the corrections. There you go:

```
name = input("What's your name?:")
print("Hi "+ name + " how do you do.")
age = input("How old are you " + name + " ?:")
print("Great " + name + "I'm " + age + " years old too.")
city = input("Which city do you come from " + name + " ?:")
print("What a coincidence, I am from " + city + " too.")
print(name + " , here is your record //: ")
print(name + " " + age + " " + city)
```

Good luck with learning Python :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for this.
I've changed the code, however, when I click CMD-B to run it, and the first question appears, "What's your name?", I type my answer i.e. Rob, and then click the Enter key, I assumed this would count the user input and then put out the response and the next question, but this isn't happening

Comment: Several of the changes here are unnecessary. `print()` allows you to concatenate values with commas just fine, though you can't do that in the arguments to `input()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = input() //for string
b = int(input()) //for int
c = float(input()) //for float
```

Comment: There is more to the question than just the title. Please address the question asked.

Answer (score -2):

```
 name=input("What's your name?:")
 print("Hi"+name+"how do you do.")
 age=input("How old are you "+name+" ?:")
 print("Great "+name," I'm ",age+" years old too.")
 city=input("Which city do you come from "+name+" ?:")
 print("What a coincidence, I am from "+city+" too.")
 print(name+", here is your record //")
 print(name+age+city)
```

Use `+` for concatenation inside `print`